# Fastest way to run complex query in large SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have SQL data that contains two table named `buletin` and `pasarbubar`.
I wanna get data using this query :

```
SELECT
    b.date_time,
    b.Type,
    b.duration,
    (SELECT MAX(`0`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f0_max,
    (SELECT MAX(`1`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f1_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`2`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f2_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`3`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f3_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`4`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f4_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`5`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f5_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`6`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f6_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`7`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f7_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`8`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f8_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`9`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f9_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`10`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f10_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`11`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f11_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`12`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f12_max,
     (SELECT MAX(`13`) FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
     WHERE e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)) AS f13_max
FROM bul.buletin b
```

For this time to run that query I usually run using phpmyadmin, to get 25 rows data it take 1 hour. Even though the total data that I have to get is as much as 3000 rows data. Maybe anyone can help me to modify my query or suggest in `python` or `php` script.

*Note : Here my data sample

Pasarbubar table
[image: pasarbubar table]

Buletin table

[image: buletin table]

Comment: i made a comment to replace `MAX(\`0\`)` as a constent `0` and so on, untill a was stuck by the realisation that you use numbers as columns because i noticed the backticks to late.. i would suggest investing some time make this better normalized if possible and the application does not depend to much on this structure.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 13 select  max .. from 
you could use a single query

```
  SELECT MAX(`0`) f0_max
    , MAX(`1`) f1_max
    , MAX(`2`) f2_max
    , MAX(`3`) f3_max
    , MAX(`4`) f4_max
    , MAX(`5`) f5_max
    , MAX(`6`) f6_max
    , MAX(`7`) f7_max
    , MAX(`8`) f8_max
    , MAX(`9`) f9_max
    , MAX(`10`) f0_max
    , MAX(`11`) f11_max
    , MAX(`12`) f12_max
    , MAX(`13`) f13_max  
  FROM rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar e
  INNER JOIN bul.buletin b ON  e.ss_time BETWEEN b.date_time 
        AND DATE_ADD(b.date_time, INTERVAL 10 SECOND)
```

and be sure you have a  proper index on

```
 table rsam_bpptkg.pasarbubar column ss_time 

 table  bul.buletin on clumn date_time
```